# how to upload a file to blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

When i submit upload form, following error is displayed.
How can i solve it?

> 404 Not Found
>   The resource could not be found.

python code

```
class DashboardHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/(mysitename)/upload', UploadHandler),
debug=True)
```

HTML(template)

```
<form action={{upload_url}} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file">
  <input type="submit" name="UPLOAD">
</form>
```

i'm using an original domain, so the error URL is as follow.

http://www.(MySiteName).me/_ah/upload/AMmfu6b74Szd5r2OSm0DYxF4sZ4tQNW7JjIDqaNwagaKRvy4eptgqc-WVRKIBd6w_SBFnpN7tjVaNujW_H7U5ftmmYT34fTnD_TjsyawkE1VTj6OrYCpsxQwO7RRnLj6yOfWLOdJbg6A/ALBNUaYAAAAAUpGu2FSrupya8eMAP-afGYgToYnHa9aD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give many details so it is hard to diagnose.  Are you using a `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler` instead of the regular `RequestHandler`?  If so, please show that handler and the relevant portion of your `WSGIApplication` setup.